# Call a program with threading daemon in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, signals

I have an encryption project in python and I want to write an end-to-end test for whole project.

I can run the project in the command line, like this:

```
> python -m  serve -c config.json
```

for an end to end test, I wrote this test function, but when I ran it, an error occurs while everything in a simple run of the project from the command line is fine.

```
def test_assert_end_to_end(self):
    args = []

    config = load_config(args, "config.json")

    t = threading.Thread(target=serve.run, name='serve', args=(args, ))
    t = threading.Thread(target=serve.run, name='serve', args=(config,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    self.unseal()

    plain_data = bytes(''.join([chr(random.randint(0, 128))
                               for i in range(EndToEndTest.SIZE_OF_DATA_TO_ENCRYPT * 1024 * 1024)]), "utf-8")

    EncryptResponseBytes = self.encrypt(plain_data)
    DecryptResponseBytes = self.decrypt(EncryptResponseBytes)

    self.assertEqual(plain_data, DecryptResponseBytes)
```

This is error's log:

```
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self._graceful_exit)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main threa
```

which refers to this function:

```
    def serve(self):
        self.sealer_server.start()
        self.cipher_server.start()
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self._graceful_exit)
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this error?

Comment: The code you’ve shown doesn’t have anything to do with signals. Please show the relevant part of your code the error traceback refers to.

Comment: The obvious answer would be *don‘t use signal outside the main thread*.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: What happens if you omit the line with `signal.signal(...)`?